# JQuery, access root property of an object from within the nested property

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have an object that lists a series of validation rules, as shown below.

```
validation_rules = {
    'validate_rule1' : {
        'rule' : function(el){
            do something
            if(true){
                this.message = 'this is a numeric error';
            }
            return true;
        },
        'message' : 'this is a general error';
    },
    'validate_rule2' : {
        'rule' : function(el){
            do something
            return this.variation.variation_1(el);
        },
        'message' : 'this is a general error',
        'variation' : {
            'variation_1' : function(el){
                return true/false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The object is used by a function that executes the rule to determine if the input is valid and return the appropriate message for each of the rules that failed.

I know how to set a default message for each rule and overwrite it using the instance "this" as I did in rule1.

I can overwrite the message of rule2 passing on each variation the instance as an argument of the function.

I was wondering, is there a way to move up the scope of "this" to access the "validate_rule2" property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript `call` function to pass the scope of the parent when calling the function `variation_1`, you can pass any scope you might need.

```
fun.call(thisArg[, arg1[, arg2[, ...]]])
```

With the first argument, you can set `this` object of the function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Comment: I guess this is the closest thing to what I asked. Thanks for your time.